# Emacs not showing inline images, I created with doom emacs with org-download

Tags: org-mode, doom, images

I have an org-file, which I started with doom emacs using org-download clipboard. This results in attachment files like this:
[image]

When in doom emacs, I can do org-inline-images (org click on it) and it shows the images, but when on another computer without doom it does not work, though I have the same images in the same file structure.

If I click on the image in emacs 29, it looks up a strange path, but shows nothing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting the two variables:

```
org-attach-id-dir
org-attach-set-directory
```

to my attach folder, which is ˜/Dropbox/org1/.attach/

Now, I can see all screenshots, which is awesome.